# root element missing error

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest

This is the XML I am creating in JavaScript:

```
<root>
<GradeValueSet>
<GradeValueSetMaster SetId="0" SetName="wrwr" SetComments="werwrwr" mode="add"/>
<DetailInfo>
   <ChildInfo Name="This sfsf" Weightage="24"/>
   <ChildInfo Name="45654" Weightage="67"/>
 </DetailInfo>
</GradeValueSet>
</root>
```

I am sending this to a .aspx page and doing the following things:

```
 XmlDocument objXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            objXmlDoc.Load(Request.InputStream);
            objXmlDoc.Save("MyXML.xml");
```

It is showing an exception "root elemenet missing"

Is my XML not well formed? I think I have a valid root element.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try saving the data as plain text from the aspx page to ensure the ONLY the xml is coming through.

Depending on how you are sending the data to the page, there could be extra information which is not part of the xml. Saving the data as plain text just to test this will show exactly what data you are getting.

Also, in the XML you do not actually need an element called "root", it's just referring to the top level element in your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry forgot to add the sending XML in previous post

<root>
<GradeValueSet>
<GradeValueSetMaster SetId="0" SetName="wrwr" SetComments="werwrwr" mode="add"/>
<DetailInfo>
   <ChildInfo Name="This sfsf" Weightage="24"/>
   <ChildInfo Name="45654" Weightage="67"/>
</DetailInfo>
</GradeValueSet>
</root>